# dynamic sized arrays in a naked function

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection

Okay so here is the deal, I am injecting a DLL into a target process and have it read some of it's registers. Problem is, whenever my function is called, the size of the content I have to grab is constantly changing.

Since i can't use vectors, how would I do it if I were to store an array of bytes for which I have no idea of the size beforehand ?

Here is my code so far, which obviously doesnt compile because of C3068.

```
__declspec(naked) void _LocalHandleMessage()
{
    __asm {
        // Here i obviously have to store the data i'm sending to HandlePaquet
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        pushad
        pushfd
    }

    {
        DWORD opcode;
        DWORD size;
        std::vector<BYTE> packetContent;
        HandlePaquet(opcode, size, packetContent, true);
    }

    __asm {
        popfd
        popad
        add esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        retn
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to be able to inject the address of a class member method into the target process, but it seems that it's not possible, unless I didnt google enough.

Comment: Why can't you use vectors?  Is it because you can't use dynamic memory allocation in general for some reason?

Comment: Exactly, i need to have these bytes into one unique container. Vectors  won't be accepted because that function is naked. Just try compiling a naked function in which you'd declare an object and the compiler will bust at you.

Comment: Why not use a `static` or global vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To store data you have very simple way - **VirtualAlloc**.
- Or you can try to use static vector variable in your dll.

About injecting address - if you are talking about hooking - yes you can, you need to modify [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). You can find examples in any open source game hack.

If member method is not virtual method and doesn't exist in vtable you need to change ***call*** opcode, or just put ***jmp xxxxxxxx*** at the begining of the method.
Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x86-x64-API-Hooking-Libra) for more details

Comment: Yes, I meant hooking, sorry. Hooking the address of the method is fine. I just can't find out if hookinh the address of a _class_ method is fine.

Comment: +1, but note that even if a method is virtual, it's possible for the compiler to issue direct calls (i.e. not indirecting through the vtable) if it knows the dynamic type of the object at compile time.  And of course the compiler can also inline calls if it can see the source...

Comment: Yes, its fine. All objects of same class have common methods realization. Only class members variables are allocating when creating new object. Methods code will stay at same place forever after process start. All methods have n + 1 arguments (n = real arguments number). First argument in class method is 'this'.